# Vue continuous sync with node api

Tags: vue.js, websocket, vuejs2, stream

I need to continuously sync with backend API. What are the changes done in backend it should be reflect back to front end in vue? How to continuously sync with API? Is the only way to set interval and call API or is there a better way?

Comment: Well it's not vue specific thing but there `Websocket's exists for it.  [Socket.io](https://socket.io/)

Answer (score 2):

If you only require that the frontend receive information from the backend then you could use something called a `stream`. You could create a readable stream that your Vue app listens to.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API

If you require that the front and backend communicate with each other, then you could use web sockets:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

A very popular javascript library for this is `socket.io`.

https://socket.io/

There are a lot of guides on the internet about how to set it all up. If you have any further questions, I recommend creating separate questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

i use [Key id](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) for update real time table from json file .